# Advices - I need to develop a script with hight memory usage and long duration

Tags: php, memory

I have a new challenge today. I will develop a script that will take some large data_log (fopen) and insert it into a database. Yesterday I did my first tests, and I estimate that this script will need a week running to process the log.

I made some env configs, like `set_time_limit` and `set_memory_limit`.

But, in this first test after an while (15min), the app crashes. The machine was running in 2gb memory usage when it crashes.

The msg error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted (tried to allocate Y) in whatever.php
```

---

Please keep in mind that the script/code is ok.

Comment: which database are you using ? `LOAD DATA INFILE` is you friend for MySQL

Comment: What does the file look like - can you put a sample ?

Comment: Can you include your current loop fro importing the data

Comment: How big is your data file? What memory allocation have you given to PHP? You may have a memory leak, of course - try monitoring memory_get_usage() as the script progresses, to see where your mem requirements are growing.

Comment: Sorry guys, This question is not about how make my code better, nut how make the env and sets to run the code.

Comment: Memory usage ~1.8GB? I think there is a small possibility the code could be improved ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The script code isn't ok. You aren't timing out, you're simply running out of memory to store whatever data you are loading from the log file.

Without seeing the code or knowing the context, you should look at the following options.

1. Clean up after yourself so you don't use more and more memory. If you're reading/writing data from or to a file, make sure you clear what data is in the memory every once in a while (depends on the loop)
2. Modify the script to work with chunks of data. Make the script run every minute or so and make it shut down after you've worked with a portion of the data. This will keep the memory requirement low and you also don't have a continuously running script (easy to continue from where you stopped)

Comment: Yes, Is what I will do. But, I was wondering to do a script that run it in one time, using a limit of the memory without crashes. Without the memory leak, my log:  Memory Usage: 1783442400
 Memory Usage: 1793842400
 Memory Usage: 1804242400

Comment: But Its Ok, I will develop as your answer me, and will log the memory usage to check the leaks. Thanks.